# C++ operator precedence in output stream

Tags: c++, cout, evaluation, operator-precedence

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int c = a*b + b==0; // c = 0
cout << a*b + b==0; // outputs 4
```

`c` evaluates to `0` because the operator precedence of the `*` and `+` operators is higher than `==` as a result of which `c` essentially evaluates to `(a*b+b)==0` which is false.

Why does putting the same expression in a `cout` statement output 4?

Comment: Because << has its own precedence which is *higher* than that of ==.

Comment: Any good book or document about C++ contains operator list with precedence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of these operators are `operator*` > `operator+` > `operator<<` > `operator==`. Then `cout << a*b + b==0;` is equivalent with `(cout << ((a*b) + b)) == 0;`.

Then the result of `((a*b) + b))`, i.e. `4` will be printed out, then the returned value of `(cout << ((a*b) + b))`, i.e. `cout` is compared with `0`. Before C++11 `cout` could be implicitly converted to `void*` via [operator void*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which returns a null pointer when steram has any errors. So here it's compared with `0` (i.e. the null pointer), and does nothing further more with the result.

Answer (score -2):

The [answr by @songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41973028/434551) already explains the behavior of code.

I want to respond to the OP by saying that it will much better to write code that is easy to follow.

If you can't clearly see the logic of the expression, simplify it. Use parenthesis to make them easier to understand. Unless you are writing code for an obfuscated code contest, there is no excuse for writing such code.

Transform those line

```
int c = a*b + b==0; // c = 0
```

to

```
int c = (a*b) + (b==0);
```

or to

```
int c = ((a*b + b) == 0);
```

depending on your intention.